# Smart Pointers: Does a 'base' part of an object get created?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class Member {
public:
  Member() {
    std::cout << "Member::ctor" << std::endl;
    throw "Exception";
  }
  ~Member() {
    std::cout << "Member::dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};
class Base {
public:
  Base() {
    std::cout << "Base::ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Base() {
    std::cout << "Base::dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  Member* m_;
  public:
    Derived() : m_(new Member()) {
      std::cout << "Derived::ctor" << std::endl;
    }
  ~Derived() {
    if(m_) delete m_;
      std::cout << "Derived::dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
try{
  std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
  std::cout << "No Exception" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The output to the above program is:

```
Base::ctor
Member::ctor
Base::dtor
Exception
```

Don't understand why that happens. Does a part of a derived object kill the base part of the object when the object cannot be fully constructed?

Can someone explain why ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A constructor processes its member initialization list before then entering its own body.  So, in this case, `Derived()` calls `Base()` and `Member()`, in that order, before entering its own body.

`Derived()` first calls `Base()` (implicitly, since you did not explicitly specify `Base()` in `Derived()`'s member initialization list).  The body of `Base()` is entered, so you see `Base:::ctor` in the output.  No exception is thrown, so `Base()` exits normally.

`Derived()` moves on to call `Member()` next.  The body of `Member()` is entered, so you see `Member::ctor` in the output.  But then `Member()` throws an exception before exiting, so construction of the `Member` object gets aborted.

The exception enters and escapes `Derived()`, so `Derived()` is aborted as well. Since `Derived()` was aborted from inside its member initialization list, its body is NOT entered, so you DO NOT see `Derived::ctor` in the output.

Since the `Member` object was NOT fully constructed, `~Member()` is NOT called, so you DO NOT see `Member::dtor` in the output.

Since the `Base` portion of `Derived` WAS fully constructed before the exception was thrown, `~Base()` IS called automatically, so you see `Base::dtor` in the output.

Since the `Derived` object was NOT fully constructed, `~Derived()` is NOT called, so you DO NOT see `Derived::dtor` in the output.

In short, whenever an exception escapes a constructor, only the pieces of that class which have been successfully constructed (base classes and data members alike) are automatically destructed individually.  Pieces that have NOT been fully constructed are NOT automatically destructed.  This behavior is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

As the exception propagates up the call stack, it aborts any constructors it escapes, until the exception is caught, or the exception escapes `main()` causing the process to terminate.

Comment: And similarly, if you had `Member1`, `Member2`, and `Member3` in that order, and `Member2` threw an exception, the `Member1` and `Base` destructors would be called, but not either of the others.

Comment: @DanielH: that is covered by "only the pieces of that class which have been successfully constructed" in my answer

Comment: Yes, but that could also have meant “All of the bases as a group” or something. I’m clarifying that each member and each base is considered individually.